# Firefox - window.history.pushState() replacing URI-encoded spaces with actual spaces

Tags: javascript, firefox, urlencode

In my app, I'm using the `window.history.pushState()` method to passively update a url query param while a user clicks some different elements on the page. I'm using `encodeURIComponent()` on the value of the new query param, but I'm finding that, when using Firefox, encoded spaces are not being passed into the url, though other special characters are being appropriately encoded. This behavior

Here's the function in question:

```
function updateUrlQueryParam(queryParamValue) {
  const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(queryParamValue).toLowerCase();
  window.history.pushState({}, '', `index.html?cat=${encodedValue}`);
}
```

If I call it with something like `updateUrlQueryParam('Foo, bar')`, the url is updated to `inventory.html?cat=foo%2c bar` (note the space!). However, if I throw a `console.log(encodedValue)` in between the two lines, I get the correctly formatted `foo%2c%20bar`.

Has anyone else encountered this behavior? Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, this is a _feature_ of Firefox. Here's a blog post with some more details on this behaviour: http://www.justarrangingbits.org/firefox-magic-decoding-address-bar/index.html (tl;dr: it's nothing to worry about). This behaviour has also been reported as a bug in Firefox; you can find reports here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?short_desc=encode&resolution=---&query_format=advanced&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&component=Address%20Bar&product=Firefox. AFAIK, there isn't a way to change this behaviour via the browser config but you might find an extension if it really bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @wing for the answer - this is expected behavior, apparently.